# memcpy a 3d pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

How can I memcpy a 3d pointer to another 3d? I already tried the following:

```
void somefunction(ArrayBlock **** b1, int noOfBlocks, ArrayBlock **** b2){  
   memcpy((&b2), (&b1), noOfBlocks*sizeof(ArrayBlock));
}
```

This gives me the following error in gdb:

```
[Inferior 1 (process 8528) exited with code 030000000005]
```

both b1 and b2 were allocated memory in the main function like this:

```
ArrayBlock ***b2;
b2 = malloc(max_x * sizeof(ArrayBlock **));
for (i = 0; i < max_x; ++i)                             
{
    b2[i] = malloc(max_y * sizeof(ArrayBlock *));
    for (j = 0; j < max_y; ++j)
    {
        b2[i][j] = malloc(max_z* sizeof(ArrayBlock));
    }
}
```

---

Solution:

I figured that because the initialization of my 3D pointer (array) was non-contiguous, one memcpy will not be enough.

so this is what I did:

```
int i2, j2;
for(i2 = 0; i2 < max_x; i2++){
  for(j2 = 0; j2 < max_y; j2++){
    memcpy(&(*b2)[i2][j2][0], &(*b1)[i2][j2][0], max_z*sizeof(ArrayBlock));
  }
}
```

I think this time it works for real, thanks to those who helped me.

Comment: Because there's no such thing as a "3D pointer". There are 3D arrays, and pointers-to-pointer-to-pointer, and they are not the same. [See this](c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

Comment: Why for the God's sake would you pass `***`?

Comment: the address of a `***` is a `****`, LOL

Comment: Do you realize that `&b1` retrieves an address of local variable regardless what you pass to that function?

Comment: would &(*b1) work instead?

Comment: With a 3D array allocated this way (the most common one), no it wouldn't work because the buffers containing the actual values are not contiguous.

Comment: NOPE DON'T memcpy THE POINTERS! If you have to memcpy the pointers, you've done something wrong. It will result in the two arrays **sharing** these pointers, and a shitstorm of epic proportions when you try to free the arrays.

Comment: Yes, for non-contiguous arrays, the multiple memcpys should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends how your 3D array was allocated, but in the most common case (array of arrays of arrays) the answer is no.

There *is* a way to allocate a 3D array in such way that it's possible, however:

- Allocate a single CX*CY*CZ array of Stuffs (`Stuff* pXyz`)
- Allocate a single CX*CY array of pointers to Stuff (`Stuff** ppXy`)
- Initialize it with pointers to various areas of `pXyz` (`ppXy[x*CY + y] = &pXyz[x*CY*CZ + y*CZ + 0];`)
- Allocate a single CX array of pointers to pointers to Stuff (`Stuff*** pppX`)
- Initialize it with pointers to various areas of `ppXy` (`pppX[x] = &ppXy[x*CY + 0];`)
- `return pppX;`

I hope I didn't get these wrong, but it's the base idea: One dimension, one malloc.

```
Stuff*** Alloc3DArray(size_t cx, size_t cy, size_t cz) {
    Stuff*** ret = NULL;

    /*Allocate a single CX*CY*CZ array of Stuffs*/
    Stuff* pXyz = malloc(cx * cy * cz * sizeof(*pXyz));
    if(pXyz!=NULL) {
        /*Allocate a single CX*CY array of pointers to Stuff*/
        Stuff** ppXy = malloc(cx * cy * sizeof(*ppXy));
        if(ppXy!=NULL) {
            /*Allocate a single CX array of pointers to pointers to Stuff*/
            Stuff*** pppX = malloc(cx * sizeof(*pppX));
            if(pppX!=NULL) {

                /*Initialize ppXy with pointers to various areas of pXyz*/
                size_t x, y;
                for(x=0 ; x<cx ; x++){
                    for(y=0 ; y<cy ; y++){
                        ppXy[x*cy + y] = &pXyz[x*cy*cz + y*cz + 0];
                    }
                }

                /*Initialize pppX with pointers to various areas of ppXy*/
                for(x=0 ; x<cx ; x++){
                    pppX[x] = &ppXy[x*cy + 0];
                }

                /*Success!*/
                ret = pppX;
            } else {
                /*Allocating third level failed: free first and second levels*/
                free(ppXy), ppXy=NULL;
                free(pXyz), pXyz=NULL;
            }
        } else {
            /*Allocating second level failed: free first level*/
            free(pXyz), pXyz=NULL;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

With this, you can memcpy this:

```
memcpy(&pppDest[0][0][0], &pppSource[0][0][0], CX*CY*CZ*sizeof(***pppDest));
```

---

**Added:** And when you're done with the array, if you've done it right it can be freed thusly:

```
void Free3DArray(Stuff ***pppArr) {
    if(pppArr != NULL) {
        free(**pppArr); /*Free third level*/
        free( *pppArr); /*Free second level*/
        free(  pppArr); /*Free first level*/
    }
}
```

Comment: so it means I should memcpy it one element at a time?

Comment: @user2847666 Do you want to copy the pointer or the whole array?

Comment: I only want to copy the values of one pointer to the other. I don't want to copy an address as b1 will change later but b2 should not.

Comment: I did as you pointed out, I no longer get an error, I will test the contents and get back soon!

Comment: @Medinoc Note that this answer is a horrible suggestion. If one needs a 3D array, one really needs `T (*arr)[y][z] = malloc(x * sizeof *arr);`.

Comment: @Medinoc VLAs can do this fine.

Comment: @H2CO3 Wait, how to you return a heap-allocated VLA pointer from a function?